# How can I control the KDE monitor configuration from a script?

Tags: multiple-monitors, scripts, kde

Every morning I come to work, plug in my sleeping laptop into the large monitor on my desk, and then fiddle with this dialog:

[image: screenshot of KDE "display settings" dialog]

I imagine that the result of this fiddling is that the "Display Settings" app writes the new monitor configuration to some file, and then sends some signal to the window manager to notice that the settings have changed.  I would like to do this myself and control it directly, for this purpose as well as others.

If I could find out the name of the process that produces the ‘Display Settings’ dialog I could run it with `strace` and see what it is doing, but I haven't been able to find that out either.

My questions are:

> To what program does this dialog belong?  What would I look for in the `ps` output to identify it?  And what is it actually doing when it changes the monitor configuration?

I am using KDE 4.8.5.

Answer (score 7):

The `xrandr` utility can be controlled from a script.  The configuration shown in the screenshot can be obtained by running the command:

> ```
> xrandr \
>  --output LVDS-1 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 1080x1120 --rotate normal \ 
>  --output DVI-D-1 --off --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate left
> ```

To *generate* this command line, I used `arandr`.  It presents a dialog something like the one in the original question, but simpler, and then has a "save" option which saves the correct `xrandr` invocation to a file.

After using the `arandr` dialog to configure the monitors the way I want them, I save the configuration to a file, say `~/.screenlayout/office.sh`.  Executing this file as a shell script restores the saved configuration.  I wrote a trivial shell script, `disp`, which executes `$HOME/.screenlayout/$1.sh`, so when I get to the office I just type `disp office` on the command line to restore the office monitor configuration.  When I go home I type `disp 1`, which runs `~/.screenlayout/1.sh`, where I have saved the default one-monitor configuration.

Still no answers to the other questions in my post, although *probably* the dialog in the original question is running `xrandr` itself to change the screen configuration.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back with the solution. Please accept your own answer as the solution. :)

Comment: @Sparhawk No, because the questions in the original post remain unanswered.

Comment: Oh okay. I thought this answer essentially made your other specific questions moot. The program is called "systemsettings". `ps aux|grep [s]ystemsettings` identifies it for me. And yes, I believe xrandr is the backend. I had a [situation](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=225&t=117052) where I didn't have this panel, and I installed `kde-workspace-randr`, which fixed it. I presume from the name that xrandr is the backend.

Comment: Thanks very much! I will probe `systemsettings` and see if I can confirm that it is using `xrandr` to set the display.

Comment: No problem. One complicating factor is that I can also access a similar system setting ("Display configuration" instead of "Size & Orientation") with `krandrtray`, then clicking the panel icon. So I suspect that there are multiple ways of launching settings. (Also, to get process names of windows in general, you can use "Show system activities"; default shortcut is Ctrl+Esc.)

Comment: This solution works partially for me. I have a dual monitor in office and I use Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty. Every time I plug in the two monitors in my office, I need to configure them in 'display settings' in Gnome Unity. While arandr sort of worked for me but sometimes the monitor is itself not detected from mini-display port. Unplugging and plugging in again detects it whereas sometimes I can just change the setting in 'display settings'. Also, the program launcher is located on the other monitor rather than on the one I want. Not sure how to configure that.

Comment: Is there no way to save the entire monitor settings and restore them when required?